# How long are $AO$ and $OC$?

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $O$ is a point on $AC$ such that $BO$ bisects angle $B$. Side $BC$ is 33 units long, side $BA$ is 15 units long, and side $AC$ is 21 units long. How long are $AO$ and $OC$?

I had a hard time with this problem.

[image]

So I did:

$$\frac{15}{33}=\frac{AO}{OC}=\frac{x}{y}$$

but im not sure how the $21$ units play into this. Any help?

Comment: It is used as $x+y=21$

Comment: Why is 15/33=AO/OC? I don't think these triangles are similar. And BOC and BOA are probably not right angles...the drawing is misleading.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog It's an [angle bisector property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).

Comment: @user236182 Ah ok, thanks

Comment: Now solve the system of equations $\begin{cases}\frac{15}{33}=\frac{x}{y}\\x+y=21\end{cases}$.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog: You can get it from the law of sines, and the fact that supplementary angles (angles who sum up to $\pi$ radians $= 180$ degrees) have equal sines.

Comment: the triangles are definitely NOT similar (they both have BO as sides and equal angle so if the were similar they would be congruent which they obviously are not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** From the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), we have $\dfrac{AB}{BC}=\dfrac{15}{33}=\dfrac xy$.

Also, $x+y=21.$ Therefore, $x=21-y.$ Plugging the values, we get $\dfrac{21-y}{y}=\dfrac{15}{33}$.

Solve this, and you get the value of *y*, which helps you obtain the corresponding value of *x*.